# Multiple users on one server working from a github repo?

Tags: git

We have 4 users trying to work from a private github repo. Each user has a github account. We have a Development server with four "sandbox directories" that these users use will work in and push/pull to the private repo on github. Now, being pretty new to this whole thing I am tying to figure out what our SSH key setup needs to be.

A deploy key is what I though we needed - but it is only linked to one users account on the server so correct me if I am wrong - but all four users on our DEV server can't use the same deploy key.

Then I thought that each user could setup a SSH key for there account on our DEV server - but I think that github only allows one key per server/pc - am I right? Maybe we can setup a user for git?

Answer (score 2):

Each user should have their own SSH key and set it up on their account at github.

The URL for that page is:

```
http://git.mybdev.com/account
```

The private repository owner should then add each user as Collaborators.  To add them as collaborators, the user with the private repository would go to the admin page for the repository and use Collaborator section on the right.

The URL format for that page is:

```
https://github.com/<user>/<project>/edit
```

You should not be setting up one universal key for the project that everyone uses.  This removes your ability to track per user contributions.

Comment: Thank you this solves the problem. I was thinking as KEYS as pass codes to access code when they are really identifiers for the commiters. 

Each user now, has their own key on the DEV server and they just pasted the public RSA into their github account as you stated.

Comment: Great, love to hear how it worked out :)